# fatal error: 'GL/glu.h' file not found although path included

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glut

I installed OpenGL through `brew install mesa` and `brew install freeglut` on my m1 mac and wrote this `hello_opengl.cpp`:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.5, -0.5);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello, OpenGL!");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

My current `.bash_profile` is

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/freeglut/3.4.0/include:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH"
export LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH"
```

and when I want to compile it as:

```
g++ hello_opengl.cpp -o hello_opengl -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT
```

I get this error.

```
fatal error: 'GL/glu.h' file not found
```

I also tried this.

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mesa/22.3.6/include:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH"
export LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH"
```

However, although I double-checked, nothing works.
Does anyone know where I am wrong?

Comment: *my current `.bash_profile` is:*, *i also tried*. So you are guessing instead of researching the issue. Please show `g++ --version`

Comment: In what directory is `glu.h` installed?

Comment: ```Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: i don't know, when i delete `glu.h`, this time it gives the error of `glut.h`!

Comment: Do `find /opt/homebrew/ -name glu.h` and it should tell you the path. You can also try `pkg-config --cflags --libs gl glu` but I'm not sure if Mac uses `pkg-config`.

Comment: I am not sure if Apple Clang supports those environment variables. Use `-I` and `-L` compiler flags.

Comment: thanks for help ted, but `glut.h` is at `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/freeglut/3.4.0/include/GL/glut.h` and `gl.h` is at `/opt/homebrew//Cellar/mesa/22.3.6/include/GL/gl.h`. are you guys know any ways to install apart brew?

Comment: Try `g++ hello_opengl.cpp -o hello_opengl -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/freeglut/3.4.0/include -I/opt/homebrew//Cellar/mesa/22.3.6/include -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT`